# How to calculate the downloaded file size and total data to be downloaded

Tags: java, sockets, stream, file-transfer

How to calculate the amount of data downloaded and the total data to be downloaded using socket.

E.G. 500kb/95000kb...95000kb/95000kb

Here i included my code for your reference.

```
private static void updateFile() {
    Socket socket = null;
    PrintWriter writer = null;
    BufferedInputStream inStream = null;
    BufferedOutputStream outStream = null;

    try {
        String serverName = System.getProperty("server.name");

        socket = new Socket(serverName, 80);
        writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        inStream = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        outStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("XXX.txt")));

        // send an HTTP request
        System.out.println("Sending HTTP request to " + serverName);

        writer.println("GET /server/source/path/XXX.txt HTTP/1.1");
        writer.println("Host: " + serverName + ":80");
        writer.println("Connection: Close");
        writer.println();
        writer.println();

        // process response
        int len = 0;
        byte[] bBuf = new byte[8096];
        int count = 0;

        while ((len = inStream.read(bBuf)) > 0) {
            outStream.write(bBuf, 0, len);
            count += len;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error in update(): " + e);
        throw new RuntimeException(e.toString());
    } 
    finally {
        if (writer != null) {
            writer.close();
        }
        if (outStream != null) {
            try { outStream.flush(); outStream.close(); } catch (IOException ignored) {ignored.printStackTrace();}
        }
        if (inStream != null) {
            try { inStream.close(); } catch (IOException ignored) {ignored.printStackTrace();}
        }
        if (socket != null) {
            try { socket.close(); } catch (IOException ignored) {ignored.printStackTrace();}
        }
    }
}
```

Please advice to achieve this and thanks in advance.

Comment: Not is possible directly. If you try download a file. i recommend you use a class like HttpURLConnection and use: connection.getContentLength() to know the total size of data to be download. With socket is possible but you need first the headers of the content and get example the value of "content-length"

Comment: The line terminator in HTTP is `\r\n`, not whatever `println()` may give you. Don't implement HTTP yourself when there is support built in and any number of third party clients. It's non-trivial. See RFC 2616 for why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The socket in general does not know the size of receiving data. A socket is bound to a TCP connection and TCP does not provide any information about data size. It is task for the application protocol and it is HTTP in your example.

HTTP indicates the data size in the `Content-Length` header. The HTTP response looks like:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 13
Connection: keep-alive

<html></html>
```

The HTML response contains header and body. The body is separated from header by a newline. The `Content-Length` header contains the size of the body in bytes.

So you may either parse the header and find the length or use an existing class like `java.net.HttpURLConnection`.